# Can I log the unhandled VCR request body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vcr

I'm using the [VCR](http://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-3/docs) gem to mock HTTP queries. I've recorded cassettes, but then I had to change some stuff around, and now I'm getting an error:

```
An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
  POST http://api.endpoint.here/path.json
```

Now, because it's a POST request, the VCR is configured to match those on body as well as path. Can I log or dump the body of the unhandled request so I can tweak the cassettes accordingly? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Won't callback achieve what you need?

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.after_http_request do |request, response|
    if request.method == :post
      puts "POST Request:#{request.uri}"
      puts "#{request.to_hash}" # or request.body
    end
  end
  c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
end
```